# javascript - object init function similar to php's __construct?

Tags: javascript, initialization, init

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Constructors in Javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects)

I have a simple JS object such as the following:

```
MyObj = {
    var: 'text',

    fn1: function(){

    },

    fn1: function(){

    }
}
```

Is there a default function such as _init() or _construct() that is executed when the object is initialized at runtime?

Comment: That solution reference is not even close to what I'm asking for... There is a BIG difference between setting variables at init and executing functions at init...

Comment: And note that since Javascript is not exactly an OOP language, OOP features like constructors can be a bit awkward to replicate. You might be better off changing your code to fit the language rather than the other way around.