# javascript - creating netrual consractor

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Constructors in Javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects)

im trying to learn how to create class's in javascript. I found that is very diffuclt for me to understand it.

now, i want to know if is possible to create a constractor in javascript, like we can do in c# or other programming languages.

i tried few things:

way 1:

```
    function SiteProfile(_url) {
    this.url = "";
    this.name = this.ExtractNameFromURL();
}

    SiteProfile.prototype.ExtractNameFromURL = function () {
        var firstDOT = this.url.indexOf(".");
        var secondDOT = this.url.indexOf(".", firstDOT + 1);
        var theName = "";
        for (var i = firstDOT + 1; i < secondDOT; i++) {
            theName += this.url[i];
        }
        return theName;
}
```

way 2:

```
function Site() {

    this.url = "";
    this.name = "";

    this.Site = function (_url) {
        this.url = _url;
        this.name = this.ExtractNameFromURL();
    }

    this.ExtractNameFromURL = function () {
        var firstDOT = this.url.indexOf(".");
        var secondDOT = this.url.indexOf(".", firstDOT + 1);
        var theName = "";
        for (var i = firstDOT + 1; i < secondDOT; i++) {
            theName += this.url[i];
        }
        return theName;
    }
}
```

both of class's should take a URL, and just get the name from him with out the www. or the .com

i want to know if i can design a class, that i can create an instance like so:

```
 var site = new SiteProfile("www.google.co.il");
 document.write(site.name); // becuse, this do nothing
```

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're real close. The problem with your first form is simply that you are not setting the `url` property with the `_url` parameter.

```
function SiteProfile(_url) {
    //change the line below to:
    //this.url = _url;
    this.url = "";
    this.name = this.ExtractNameFromURL();
}

SiteProfile.prototype.ExtractNameFromURL = function() {
    var firstDOT = this.url.indexOf(".");
    var secondDOT = this.url.indexOf(".", firstDOT + 1);
    var theName = "";
    for (var i = firstDOT + 1; i < secondDOT; i++) {
        theName += this.url[i];
    }
    return theName;
}
var site = new SiteProfile("www.google.co.il");
document.write(site.name); // with the change above, this will behave as expected
```

Here's the fiddle for the first form: http://jsfiddle.net/BCnfx/

The problem with the second form is two-fold. The main function should be called "SiteProfile" if you still want to instantiate it as such. The second problem is that you need to initialize the `url` property by passing in the url to the `Site` method.

```
//function below should be called "SiteProfile", not "Site"
function Site() {
    this.url = "";
    this.name = "";

    this.Site = function(_url) {
        this.url = _url;
        this.name = this.ExtractNameFromURL();
    };

    this.ExtractNameFromURL = function() {
        var firstDOT = this.url.indexOf(".");
        var secondDOT = this.url.indexOf(".", firstDOT + 1);
        var theName = "";
        for (var i = firstDOT + 1; i < secondDOT; i++) {
            theName += this.url[i];
        }
        return theName;
    };
}

//now instantiate like this instead.
var site = new SiteProfile();
site.Site("www.google.co.il");
document.write(site.name); // with the changes above, this will behave as expected
```

Here's the fiddle for the second form: http://jsfiddle.net/BCnfx/1/

Comment: thank pete, i understand now that there is a constractors in javascript afther all.

Answer (score 1):

in your first example:

```
function SiteProfile(_url) {
    this.url = _url;
    this.name = this.ExtractNameFromURL();
}
```

then you will be able to do :

```
var site = new SiteProfile("www.google.co.il");
 document.write(site.name);
```

Comment: wierd, becuse i tried runing that, and nothing happend. (didnt see the name)

Comment: this.url = _url; << is different to your posted code.

Comment: thanks, now i see what i did worng. so afther all there is Constractors to javascript. cool!

Comment: i first choose you becuse you were the first, but i guess u right he kinda deserve it. but u got upvote and a big thank you! :)