# What does this way mean?

Tags: javascript

I got a JavaScript source code, and I don not understand something in this. Could you help me please, what does it mean?

```
Partnerek = (function () {

    Partnerek = function () { }

    //there are functions in this way
    //I think this is a public function
    Partnerek.foo = function foo()
    {
      //code
    }

    //there are functions in this way
    //this is a non public function
     function foosecondway()
    {
      //code
    }

    return Partnerek;
})()
```

It seems like a class, but this is not a class.

1. What is this?
2. Why Did the programmer write in this way?
3. Is this a good way?
4. What is the return value?
5. Is the two function "Parameter" same in the code?

Comment: This is fairly typical modern Javascript code. Are you looking for a extensive tutorial in Javascript? There are lots of guides and tutorials over the net, but StackOverflow is not a good place to look for personal tutoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but to me it looks like it's a class buildup, which executes itself. so if you would call

```
var test = new Partnerrek()
```

This variable will become an instance of this class(This is done by the return) and the constructor

```
Partnerek = function(){}
```

Will be called.

Comment: Why is this way good? Is this slowwer, is not this? When I call this, this always calls the function, does not this? I have already tested, what will happen if I give the partnerek to the object. And I am able to use that like a class, but I did not use the new world, when I made that. nom I am a little bit confused? Can you explain this please, or tell something about it. Would the simple class way faster?

Comment: what do you mean by simple class exactly? As Lanzz commented, this is a modern way to build a js-class. I've been checking it out a little more and I think that by wrapping a function around it, this class will have closure & private scope, which can come in quite handy, perhaps this explains it a little better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects