# Self-Executing Functions on Instantiation in a Javascript Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, inheritance

I have a class in Javascript based on this [Base Class](http://joshgertzen.com/object-oriented-super-class-method-calling-with-javascript/) by Josh Gertzen. I'd like the class to self-execute an 'initialize' function for adding event listeners when it's instantiated. Is this possible?

This is in my main application script:

```
var mainView = new MainView(model)

/*the line I want to remove but don't know how*/
mainView.initialize();
```

And this is the method setting up the listener inside of the class extension.

```
initialize : function ()
{
    $(document).on("Loading", this.addPreloader);
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Run `this.initialize()` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function MainView(someParameter){
        this.property = null;

        this.initialize = function(someParameter){
             /* construction code */
            this.property = 'test';
        };

        this.initialize();
    };


var main = new MainView();
console.log(main.property);
```

This will help i think. You can also look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects) for more information about **javascript** and **constructors**.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kex4a/)

Comment: Thank you! It was obvious but I didn't think of that :) Thanks for the link too, I will check it out.