# JS constructor not workning

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115565/1003886) answer to create a JS constructor:

```
function ObjectOne(value) {
  var myVal = value;
}

function ObjectTwo(val) {
  this.val = val;
}
```

And i want to access that variable like this: `new ObjectOne("asdf").myVal` but that doesn't work (returns undefined)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2pR7/1/)

EDIT: IM RETARDED

There was typo in ObejctOne and ObjectTwo, (ill bury myself deep)

[new version](http://jsfiddle.net/q2pR7/2/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared with `var` in the constructor are private variables that can't be accessed from outside the constructor.

To get the value of that variable, you'll have to provide a getter method:

```
function ObjectOne(value) {
    var myVal = value;
    this.getMyVal () {
        return myVal;
    }
}
```