# javascript , use this.attrName in a function which name is also attrName

Tags: javascript, this

I found something strange..

```
function Man(){
    this.Man = "Peter";
}
```

after I call it. (not use it as a constructor)

```
Man()
```

I think a result will be

```
alert(Man.Man)//-->Peter
```

but.. I'm wrong , actually the result is :

```
alert(Man.Man)//-->undefined
alert(Man)//-->Peter
```

That was really confusing ,how it happened??

Comment: `alert(Man)//-->Peter`? Are you sure?

Comment: When you `alert` `Man` -> `alert(Man)` - it should return the hole function not just its property. http://jsfiddle.net/m5BQE/

Comment: Check what `this` actually refers to.

Comment: yeah ... I have try it in chrome console

Comment: got it = =   this refer to window..when a function was called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain you what is happening there.

### 1

```
function Man(){
    this.Man = "Peter";
}
```

The `this` in  `Man()` function is `window`.

### 2

```
Man();
```

You are calling the function. Which sets the global variable `Man`'s value to `"Peter"`.

Note that `this.Man = "Peter"` is equal to `window.Man = "Peter"` as `this` is referring to the `window`.

### 3

```
alert(Man.Man)
```

The function call `Man();` in step 2 has made the `Man` from a function to a string variable. Now `Man` is a variable whose value is a string and it doesn't contain the property `Man`, so it is `undefined`.

### 4

```
alert(Man)
```

Now, you are actually alerting the global variable which was created in `Man()` call and it was set the value of `"Peter"`

Comment: glad to have helped ;) @Joey

Answer (score 1):

I used the chrome console and had some other findings

```
function Man(){
    this.Man = "Peter";
    console.log("this", this);
}
```

Above this refers to Window. If you call the function `Man()` nothing is returned since the function does not return anything but sets the property Man on the window-object to be `Peter`. Your line `Man.Man` should return `undefined` in chrome. If you use `Man().Man` you will get undefined as well since `this` refers to the window object and the function `Man()` has no property `Man`. You could write

```
function Man(){
    this.Man = "Peter";
    return this.Man;
}
```

This returns the value `Peter`. If you want to have a property `Man` you could use a [constructor function](http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor) write

```
// set this.Man == window.Man to Peter    
function Man() { this.Man = "Peter"; } 

// create an constructor for each object Man
Man.prototype = { constructor: this.Man } 

// create an object 
var man = new Man(); 

// call his property which was set in the constructor of the prototype
man.Man;
```

Please ask for more help if anything is unclear.

#### Update as response to the comment

You can use a constructor without using prototype (see [examples at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#Examples) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects) if you use this syntax:

```
function Box(color) // Constructor
{
    this.color = color;
}

var redBox = new Box("red");
var blueBox = new Box("blue");

redBox.color; // returns red
blueBox.color; // returns blue
```

To understand where `this` refers to you can take a look at [understanding javascript this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/). In the box-example `this` refers to the new instance (object) of the "underlying class function".  In  `function Man(){this.Man = "Peter"}` the `this` refers to this.window. You can read more [about protype in this book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html#key11).

Comment: you got me confused - -..  I think when use function Man as a constructor , I don't have to define `Man.prototype = {constructor:this.man}` explicit, and where is  **this** refers to ?  and I have another question, When we define a `function` , there was implicit definition of `function.prototype`, and `function.prototype.constructor == function`am I right?

Comment: You are right - see my update above. Regarding prototype, constructor and this i will try to find a good explanation.