# Call a function to return a class calculated within the class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm currently doing the below, calling it via this line: `var newNumbers = GetNumberClass( 5 );`

```
class NumberClass
{
    var num1 = 2;
    var num2 = 3;
}

function GetNumberClass ( add : int )
{
    var n = new NumberClass();
    n.num1 += add;
    n.num2 += add + 10;
    return n;
}
```

I feel like I might have once read a better way to do this, but can't remember exactly how or the terminology, but does something along these lines exist?

```
class NumberClass
{
    var num1 = 2;
    var num2 = 3;

    function GetNumberClass ( add : int )
    {
        num1 += add;
        num2 += add + 10;
        return NumberClass;
    }
}
```

My examples are in Unityscript but I would understand an answer in either that or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constructors in C#

```
class NumberClass
{
    var num1 = 2;
    var num2 = 3;

    public NumberClass(int add)
    {
        num1 += add;
        num2 += add + 10;
    }
}
```

And in Unityscript you can do the same, see [Constructors in JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects) and [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/133459-UnityScript-Constructor-Issue)

```
class NumberClass
{
    var num1 = 2;
    var num2 = 3;

    function NumberClass(add : int)
    {
        num1 += add;
        num2 += add + 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Essential No problem! You can also have multiple different constructors with different parameters