# JS using class variable

Tags: javascript

I know there's no class in JS, but there's something like class, what is really weird for me. I'm quiet new to JS, and I'm trying to build a simple "class". This is how I tried:

```
Game = new function() {
   this.action_finish = 0;
   this.thick = function() {
      $('#action-finish').text(Game.action_finish--);
      setTimeout(this.thick, 1000);
   };
};
```

This is how it worked for me, and I'm wondering, why `this.action_finish` (returns NaN) does not work in `thick` function instead of `Game.action_finish`. Could anyone explain why does it work like this? I've been developing in PHP and C# for years an this approach is hard for me to understand.

Ps.: I don't need more instances of this class, and I'd like to use it like a class that's why I'm using the new keyword.

**Edit:** 
This is how I'm using it:

```
Game.action_finish = 10;
Game.thick();
```

**Edit:**
Finally I solved my problem. As I tried to define my issue wasnt about the methods of declaring a class, but of reaching a class variable.

Here's the solution in case if anyone has the same problem:

```
this.thick.bind(this)
```

A little explanation can be found here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/binding

Comment: Don't use `new function(){};` to create functions. Use `function Game(){}` or `var Game = function() {};`. Or `new Function(str)` to create a function from string, but better avoid that.

Comment: Please check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects) it's exactly what you're looking for. (The `new` in your definition is not correct and you have to use prototypes to add methods to the class.)

Comment: Isn't it correct the way I'm using it?

Comment: What I'm asking is not the way of declaring, but why does this.action_finish not work INSIDE the class? Why do I have to use Game.action_finish instead of this.action_finish?

Comment: @KissKoppány You don't have to use it. `Game` should be a function in order to use it as a constructor, but it's an object because of `new function()`. Then you should create instances using `new Game()`. Then `this.action_finish` will work.