# Trying to understand the difference between prototype and constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to understand this concept. I have read many articles regarding prototypes and constructors but wherever I go I'm left with confusion.

The confusion arises when people talk about constructors and prototypes simultaneously.

In the following example

```
var employee = function Emp(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var jack = new employee("Jack Dwain");

employee.constructor // gives Function()

employee.prototype // gives Emp {}

employee.prototype.constructor // gives Emp(name)

jack.constructor // gives Emp(name)

jack.prototype // gives undefined
```

1. prototype is a way that JS achieves inheritance, since `Emp(name)` is the base function prototype is referenced to the same function itself. Is that what happened?
2. In what way do `employee.constructor` and `employee.prototype.constructor` differ?
3. Why was `jack.prototype` `undefined`? i.e. If it is inheriting from the function `Emp(name)` why didn't it reference that function?
4. How can I clearly predict (without typing in the console) what the prototype or the constructor or the prototype.constructor ......yields?

Comment: I think the constructor is the function that you call to create the object. The prototype defines what the object can do. So the prototype is larger than the constructor. See also: [Constructors in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects).

Comment: This line: `var employee = function Emp(name) { ... }` is confusing. It would be better-written as `function Emp(name) { ... }` and only using `Emp` instead of `employee`.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will explain how prototypal inheritance works in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Comment: I think it is better to observer `__proto__` instead of `prototype` for research purpose.  That will explain your last row output. i.e. `jack.prototype //gives undefined`

Comment: Are you sure employee.prototype is an  Emp object? I would think it is an instance of Object.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is pretty hard to wrap your mind around this concept if you are used to the ease of extending objects in other OOP languages, but I'll do my best to explain the uses of those and what is what. I am going to assume you are familiar with other OOP languages. Correct me if I'm wrong.

All functions have the prototype `Function()`. They are inheriting all base functionality from `Function` like `toString()` and `valueOf()`.

Then there is a constructor. That is what you use to initialize an object with.

`p = new Foo();`

So in this case we have two things.

- A `function Foo` with `Function` as prototype(Foo)
- A `Function` object with `Foo()` as constructor(p)

(following me yet?)

The `Foo()` constructor can override some base functionality of the `Function` constructor or leave it as it is and make good use of it.

If you are familiar with OOP principles, The prototype is the base class, the constructor your current class. In OOP the above would be `class Foo extends Function`

You can also start inheritance with this entire setup of prototype and constructor making more complex objects as you go whilst sharing functionality.

For example this:

```
// Make an object initialiser extending Function. In OOP `class Foo extends Function`

function Foo(bar) {
    this.baz = bar;
}
Foo.prototype.append = function(what) {
    this.baz += " " + what;
};
Foo.prototype.get() {
    return this.baz
}
```

Now lets say we want different ways to get `baz` out of there. One for console logging and one for putting it on the title bar.
We could make a big thing about our class `Foo`, but we don't do that, because we need to do wholly different things with the new classes that are made for different implementations. The only thing they need to share are the `baz` item and the setters and getters.

So we need to extend it to use an OOP term. In OOO this would be the desired end result `class Title extends Foo(){}`. So lets take a look at how to get there.

```
function Title(what) {
    this.message = what;
}
```

At this point the `Title` function looks like this:

- prototype Function
- constructor Title

So, to make it extends `Foo` we need to change the prototype.

```
Title.prototype = new Foo();
```

- prototype Foo
- constructor Foo

This is done by initializing a new `Foo()` object against the prototype.
Now its basically a `Foo` object called `Title`. That is not what we want because now we can't access the message part in `Title`.
We can make it properly extend `Foo()` by resetting the constructor to `Title`

```
Title.prototype.constructor = Title;
```

- prototype Foo
- Constructor Title

Now we are faced with one more problem. The constructor of `Foo` doesn't get initialized so we end up with an undefined `this.baz`

To resolve that we need to call the parent. In Java you would do that with `super(vars)`, in PHP `$parent->__construct($vars)`.

In Javascript we have to modify the `Title` class constructor to call the constructor of the parent object.

So the `Title` class constructor would become

```
function Title(what) {
    Foo.call(this,what);
    this.message = what;
}
```

By using the `Function` object property `Foo` inherited we can initialize the `Foo` object in the `Titl`e object.

And now you have a properly inherited object.

So instead of using a keyword like `extend` like other OOP languages it uses `prototype` and `constructor`.

Comment: Well, *puts on sunglasses* deal with it :-p

Comment: I did not understand "That is not what we want because now we cant access the message part in Title" until I understood that changing somethings prototype changes it's constructor to be the new prototype also. See second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093057/javascript-inheritance-and-the-constructor-property

Comment: Yea, but I wrote in mind that anyone reading this understands inheritance in an OOP way. From an OOP perspective this is logical to me. but maybe i'm weird like that ;-)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to create a javascript **object** you can simply declare a new object and give it properties (I've chosen to objectify myself):

```
var myself= {
    name:"Niddro",
    age:32
};
```

This method allows you to make *one* object. If what you want to have is a **prototype** describing a person in general, where you can declare several people with the same setup. To create a prototype, you can use a **constructor**, as seen below:

```
//Constructor
function generalNameForObject(param1, param2,...) {
    //Give the object some properties...
}
```

I have a prototype (a recipe) in mind that I want to call person and it should contain the properties name and age and I'll use a constructor to make it:

```
function person(name,age) {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}
```

The above construct function describes the prototype for my person objects.

Create a new person by calling the construct function:

```
var myself = new person("Niddro",31);
var OP = new person("rajashekar thirumala",23);
```

Some time passes and I realise that I've had a birthday so I need to change the property of the prototype:

```
myself.age=32;
```

If you want to **add properties to the construct**, you need to manually add it into the construct function:

```
function person(name,age,rep) {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.reputation=rep;
}
```

Instead, you can add properties to the prototype by doing the following (here "prototype" is an actual command and not just a name):

```
function person(name,age,rep) {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}
person.prototype.reputation=105;
```

note that this will add a reputation of 105 for all objects created.

I hope this has given you some more insight on the relationship between the constructor and prototype.

Comment: it was a great practical explaination, thankyou. I am a beginner, and have also seen something called `__proto__` being talked about in the similar context. is it same as `person.prototype` ?

Answer (score 9):

> employee.constructor //gives Function()

In JavaScript functions are also objects, which can be constructed using its own constructor which is [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) . So you can write following code to get a instance of Function.

```
var employee2 = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a+b');
```

Same happens when you create function using function literal like in your case. And the constructor property of this object also refers to the same native Function object/class.

> employee.prototype // gives  Emp {}

Each object in JavaScript has a prototype associated with it. Though only function objects prototype is directly accessible with the `.prototype`. This same prototype is copied on its objects prototype when you create objects with `new` keyword. Primarily this copying is responsible for the inheritance/extension. Although the prototype is copied, it is not directly asseccible like in case of Function objects. It's available in non standard way with `.__proto__` . Following code will return true.

```
jack.__proto__==employee.prototype
```

> employee.prototype.constructor //gives Emp(name)

As said in the documentation of [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) . This returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype. Here the object being refered is employee.prototype and `not employee`. This is bit complex but prototype of object employee.prototype was created by the function Emp(name)

> jack.constructor //gives Emp(name)

As said in the previous point, this objects prototype was created by function Emp(name) when you created the object using new Emp(),

> jack.prototype //gives undefined

jack is not a function object, so you cant access its prototype like that. You can access(not a standard way) the prototype of jack like following.

```
jack.__proto__
```

Answer (score 6):

**Constructor:**

```
function Foo(x) {
    this.x =x;
}
```

`Foo` is the constructor. A constructor is a function.

There are two ways to use this constructor `Foo`.

> "Objects are created by using constructors in new expressions; for
>   example, new Date(2009,11) creates a new Date object. Invoking a
>   constructor without using new has consequences that depend on the
>   constructor. For example, Date() produces a string representation of
>   the current date and time rather than an object."

Source [ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes)

That means if `Foo` returns something (via `return "somevalue";`) then `typeof Foo()` is the type of the return value.

On the other hand, when you call

```
var o = new Foo();
```

JavaScript actually just does

```
var o = new Object();
o.[[Prototype]] = Foo.prototype;
Foo.call(o);
```

**Prototype:**

When you call `o.a`, then javascript first checks if `a` is a own property of the object `o`. If not javascript will look up the property chain to find `a`.

For more information about property-chain have a look at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

The `prototype` porperty of the constructor has a really powerful feature, that is not available in classes. If it's useful is another debate. The `prototype` porperty of the constructor can alter properties of each instance that does link to that prototype in their prototype-chain.

**TL,DR:**

Note: This is not an exact definition, the purpose of the summary is just to give you a feeling about constructors and prototypes.

If you use a constructor with the `new` keyword, then constructors and prototypes have kind of similar purpose even though they are completely different. A constructor initializes properties of the object, so it provides properties. A prototype also provides properties via the property-chain (prototype-based inheritance).

Comment: I like this explanation a lot.

Answer (score 4):

**A prototype is just an object,** *while* **a constructor is a pointer to the function that created the object.**

**A constructor is a pointer.** It points to the Function() that created the point from which you are retrieving the constructor from. (i.e a constructor is just a reference to a Function() and  we can call it as many times as we want.)

One of the uses of the constructor is to help you create replicate copies of an object. Since the constructor property is a reference to the function that created the object, as long as you have a copy of the object, it will always point to the original constructor.https://coderwall.com/p/qjzbig/understanding-constructor-and-prototype

**Using an Object Constructor:**
Usually, an object created alone is limited in many situations. It only creates a single object.

Sometimes we like to have an "object type" that can be used to create many objects of one type.

The standard way to create an "object type" is to use an object constructor function:

```
function person(first, last, email ) {
  this.first_name = first;
  this.last_name = last;
  this.e_mail = email;
}
var myFather = new person("Ibm", "Muh", "ibm@gmail.com");
```

The above function (person) is an object constructor. Once you have an object constructor, you can create new objects of the same type:

```
var myFather = new person("Sul", "Ahm", "sul@gmail.com");
```

**Every JavaScript object has a prototype.
A prototype is also an object.**

All JavaScript objects inherit their properties and methods from their **prototype**.

Objects are created using 2 methods of creating an object i.e **(1)** object literal, or **(2)** with new Object(), inherit from a prototype called Object.prototype. Objects created with new Date() inherit the Date.prototype.

The Object.prototype is on the top of the prototype chain.

All JavaScript objects (Date, Array, RegExp, Function, ....) inherit from the Object.prototype.https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

**The keyword prototype is a property of Function() objects.**

Value of a **prototype** is the object constructor that created that specific object. Let's see a couple of prototypes:

```
Boolean.prototype // returns Object Boolean
String.prototype // returns Object String with methods such as "toUpperCase"
Function.prototype // returns function() {} or function Empty() {}
```

**Creating a Prototype:**

The standard way to create an object prototype is to use an object constructor function:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
}
var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50);
```

With a constructor function, you can use the new keyword to create new objects from the same prototype as shown above:

The constructor function is the prototype for Person objects.
It is considered good practice to name constructor function with an upper-case first letter.

**Adding Properties to a Prototype**

You cannot add a new property to a prototype the same way as you add a new property to an existing object, because the prototype is not an existing object.

Example:
Person.nationality = "English";

To add a new property to a prototype, you must add it to the constructor function:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
  this.nationality = "English";
}
```

All native and complex objects retrieve to their original constructors, which in this case are themselves. The only exception is the Function prototype, which returns the Function() function that created it. Don't confuse it with the constructor, as it's not the same.

```
Function.prototype === Function.constructor // returns false, Function.constructor is function Function(){}
```

There's an extra property, `__proto__`, which refers to the internal [[proto]] property of instance objects. Unlike Function() objects, every Object has a `__proto__`.
It's not recommended to update the prototype of an instance object, as prototypes are not meant to be changed on runtime (you should be able to see who's the proto of who, otherwise you need to spent extra computation in ensuring no cyclic references).

Answer (score 0):

Yet the truth is, this approach might be wrong for many situations. In Javascript when you bind a method to the this keyword, you are providing that method to only that particular instance and it does not really have any relationship with an object instance of that constructor, pretty much like a static method. Keeping in mind that functions are first-class citizens in Javascript, we can deal with them just like objects, in this case we're only adding a property to an instance of a function object. Thats only part of the story, you must also know that any method attached via this will get re-declared for every new instance we create, which could affect the memory usage of the application negatively if we wish to create so many instances.