# Javascript inheritance of properties defined with Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, inheritance, defineproperty

I have the following parent class...

```js
function Parent(id, name, parameters) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, "id", {
    value: id
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    value: name,
    writable: true
  });
};
```

and the corresponding child class:

```js
function Child(id, name, parameters) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, "phone", {
    value: parameters.phone,
    writable: true
  });
};
```

I tried to apply inheritance by adding something like
*Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);*
, but this obviously does not work.

How can I inherit from the Parent class such that I can use the properties id and name.

Comment: I suggest you read my answer here. That might help you a bit to understand how inheritance can be achieved in the prototype way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600238/trying-to-understand-the-difference-between-prototype-and-constructor-in-javascr/28600866#28600866

Comment: The solution in this post helped me a lot, I just changed Child.prototype = new Parent(); to Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to apply inheritance by adding something like `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);`

Yes, you should do that, to create a prototype chain between your `.prototype` objects. You have your methods defined on them, don't you?

> How can I inherit from the Parent class such that I can use the properties id and name.

You basically need a "super" call to the `Parent` constructor so that it sets up your properties on `Child` instances:

```
function Child(id, name, parameters) {
  Parent.call(this, id, name, parameters);
  Object.defineProperty(this, "phone", {
    value: parameters.phone,
    writable: true
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I could already read it out Michael Dibbet's post.
Besides this Parent.call I had to define the following after the function declaration:

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;