# Object object is not working as it should

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, proto

I learned about prototype and proto and i think  i understand it but this just doesn't make sense? Can somebody explain to  me why accessing directly Object like this doesn't work.

```
function createObj() {
  this.name = 'user';
  this.prezime = 'user';
}

var obj1 = new createObj();

createObj.prototype.__proto__.toString = function () {
  return 'works';
}   //obj1.toString() returns 'works'   

createObj.__proto__.__proto__.toString = function () {
  return 'this works as well';
}   //obj1.toString() returns 'this works as well  '

//Then why this doesn't work: 

Object.toString = function () {
  return true;
}
```

From my understanding I am directly changing Object `object`.

So when I do `obj1.toString()` shouldn't it go  to `prototype` and 
then `proto` inside `prototype` and find `toString()` like it does from last two examples?

Comment: Don't use `__proto__`. If it's pre-es5 it's non-standard, if it's post-es5 then you have `Object.getPrototypeOf/Object.setPrototypeOf`. Note that the latter will likely trigger a console warning. There's pretty much never a good reason to access `__proto__` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're setting a property on the `Object` **constructor**, not the `Object` **prototype** when you say `Object.toString = ...`.

[Trying to understand the difference between prototype and constructor in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600238/trying-to-understand-the-difference-between-prototype-and-constructor-in-javascr)

If you change `Object.toString = ...` to `Object.prototype.toString = ...` you get your desired result:

```js
function createObj() {
  this.name = 'user';
  this.prezime = 'user';
}

var obj1 = new createObj();

createObj.prototype.__proto__.toString = function() {
  return 'works';
} //obj1.toString() returns 'works'   

console.log(obj1.toString());

createObj.__proto__.__proto__.toString = function() {
  return 'this works as well';
}

console.log(obj1.toString());

Object.prototype.toString = function() {
  return true;
}

console.log(obj1.toString())
```