# function.constructor vs function.prototype.constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I've ready quite a bit of blog post and stackoverflow questions but can't get good understanding regarding this.

[Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor)

[Trying to understand the difference between prototype and constructor in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600238/trying-to-understand-the-difference-between-prototype-and-constructor-in-javascr)

[Constructors in JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects)

[JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093057/javascript-inheritance-and-the-constructor-property)

[Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction)

**Question**:

```js
function person(fname) {
  this.fname = fname;
}

let obj1 = new person('first'); //works well
console.log(obj1);
let obj2 = new person.prototype.constructor('second'); //works well
console.log(obj2);
//now the query
console.log(person.constructor); //1. it prints  function Function() { [native code] } what does it mean
let obj3 = new person.constructor('third') // 2. why this doesn't work ?
console.log(obj3); //
```

now as we know that a every function in javascript has a property call `prototype` which is an `object` which has a property called `constructor` which points back to the *function on which prototype object is a property*. - **correct me if I'm wrong with this**

so according to above statement
`person.prototype.constructor` === `person` (both are the same)

**Query: 1** person.constructor prints `function Function() { [native code] }` what does it means, please explain in detail.

**Query: 2** why this `new person.constructor('randon')` doesn't work ?

**Query: 3**  what exactly is `person.constructor` and how it's different from `person.prototype.constructor` ?

Answer (score 1):

Roughly:

1. Function constructors are implemented by the JS engine, the engine you're using implements it in native code (maybe they all do).
2. Define "works"; it creates a new function (see #1) with the string passed in as its body, which unsurprisingly blows up if you run the returned function. If you passed in a valid function body, it works fine, e.g.,

```
> let obj3 = new person.constructor("console.log('hi')")
> obj3()
hi
```

3. #1 and #2 answer this.