# Javascript - transform object in class

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JS and i'm used to traditional OOP languages, so i'm having a hard time making some things work properly.

Here is my example :

```
var myObject = {
prop:'something'; 
callme:function () {
  console.log('you called me');
  }
}

firstObj = myObject;
firstObj.prop1 = 'new thing';

secondObj = myObject;
secondObj.prop1 = 'second thing';
```

Obviously the 'secondObj' overrides what 'fristObj' did before. How can i convert the 'myObject' object so it can work like a class , so i can create individual new instances of it ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructors in JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects)

Comment: This reading really helped me out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a 'class' in javascript you create a function which by convention has its first character capitalized.

```
function MyClass() { }

var obj = new MyClass();
```

To attach methods to this you add it to `MyClass`'s `prototype`.

```
MyClass.prototype.callme = function () {
  console.log('you called me');
}
```

To add properties use `this` to refer to this instance of the class.

```
function MyClass() { 
  this.prop = 'something';
}
```

---

So all together:

```
function MyClass() { 
  this.prop = 'something';
}

MyClass.prototype.callme = function () {
  console.log('you called me');
}

// Remember to use var to declare variables (or they are global)
var firstObj = new MyClass();
firstObj.prop = 'new thing';

var secondObj = new MyClass();
secondObj.prop = 'second thing';
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a style of JS programming where you just make objects and functions which return objects. In your case, make `myObject` into a function which returns the hash. It will return a new one each time it's called.

```
var myObject = function() {
  return {
    prop: 'something'; 
    callme: function () {
      console.log('you called me and prop is', this.prop);
    }
  };
}

firstObj = myObject();
firstObj.prop1 = 'new thing';
firstObj.callme();

secondObj = myObject();
secondObj.prop1 = 'second thing';
secondObj.callme();
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the two good answers you already have, I wanted to point out that if you are ready to use edge stuff, ES6, the next JavaScript spec, includes classes.

Using transpilers like [babel](http://babeljs.io), you can already write ES6 code then compile it so that it can run on all browsers. It works increadibly well, especially when combined with tools like [webpack](http://webpack.github.io) that automates the process, and raises more and more adepts. It is the future, and clearly worse a try (classes are just the tip of the iceberg).

You can read more on ES6 classes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Here is one of the example they give:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea()
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

Comment: `class` in ES6 is just a syntax sugar. +1 though.

Comment: Yes (except for the `super` keyword). But syntax, sometimes is everything. Especially when you are talking about hand-made classes in JS, a subject that raises so much discussion and for which no elegant solution exists. Look at Daniel's answer, come on! Let's talk about readability :).

Answer (score 0):

A theoretical answer to a practical question. JavaScript is more traditional (take for example [SmallTalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) - one of the JavaScript grandparents) in terms of OOP than most of the current OOP languages. It is [prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), meaning that objects inherit from other objects. The constructor function is an unpleasant legacy (also called "classical inheritance") for the sake of typical OOP class imitation (in the way `class` is just a fabric for objects in most popular OOP, the typical JavaScript object is a [fabric](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for other object). Analogous example could be the [Io](http://iolanguage.org/scm/io/docs/IoTutorial.html) language (given for simplicity). IMO there is no need for separate objects' fabrics like `class`.