# Nested binding context is accessible without $parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I just started developing a Map application using knockout.js. I somewhat know how the binding context works but I don't understand how the `showCoord`
function is accessible without `$parent`. Here is the code

```js
var MapApplication = function() {
 // member function
 self = this;

 var map;

 self.locations = ko.observableArray([
  {name: 'Museum', coord: {lat: -37.669012, lng: 144.841027}},
  {name: 'Ariport', coord: {lat: -37.669012, lng: 144.841027}}
 ]);

 self.showCoord = function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.coord);
 }

 var init = function() {
  ko.applyBindings(MapApplication);
 };

 $(init);
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="places">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: locations">
 <li data-bind="click: showCoord, text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$parent` and see what happens.

In fact, try changing `ko.applyBindings(MapApplication)` to `ko.applyBindings()`. It will still work the same way.

What's happening is that `locations` is behaving like a child function of Window, and it's own parent `MapApplication` is unrecognized. This is because you haven't initialized `MapApplication`, and you cannot initialize it before it is created.

Bonus - try modifying your code like this:

```
self.showCoord = function(obj) {
   console.log(obj.coord);
   console.log(self);
}
```

and check the value of 'self'.

---

The correct way to bind would be this:

```js
var MapApplication = function() {
    // member function
    self = this;

    var map;

    self.locations = ko.observableArray([
         {name: 'Museum', coord: {lat: -37.669012, lng: 144.841027}},
         {name: 'Ariport', coord: {lat: -37.669012, lng: 144.841027}}
    ]);

    self.showCoord = function(obj) {
         console.log(obj.coord);
    }                
};
var init = function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new MapApplication());
};
$(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="places">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: locations">
        <li data-bind="click: $parent.showCoord, text: name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Update**
If you want to use IIFE, the function should not try to bind itself - it needs to bind one of its objects. So you need to add an encapsulating function and make MapApplication an object. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589069/benefit-of-declaring-knockout-view-model-using-iife). This also allows you to bind multiple objects to different parts of the html, if needed. Here's how it might look:

```js
var applyBinding = function(){
    var MapApplication =  {
        locations : ko.observableArray([
            {name: 'Museum', coord: {lat: -37.669012, lng: 144.841027}},
            {name: 'Ariport', coord: {lat: -37.669012, lng: 144.841027}}
        ]),
        showCoord :function (obj) {
            console.log(obj.coord);
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(MapApplication);
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <div class="places">
     <ul data-bind="foreach: locations">
         <li data-bind="click: $parent.showCoord, text: name"></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ray. I know the correct way would be the one you suggested but I was trying to organize the code using the module pattern and IIFE.