# JS framework for dividing the code into categories

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks

I'm looking for a JS framework, which would help me to divide the code into categories. Whenever I do any apps, I don't use any framework and even tho it's working, my code looks really untidy, it lacks a nice structure. Can you advise any nicely formatted, object oriented, MVC framework which works well with node.js apps and EJS? (besides express.js)

Comment: To organize your code, you want [modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). Asking for an MVC framework here is off-topic (software request), but a quick google search will show you a few.

Comment: The framework doesn't necessarily organize your code for you. You could check out sails.js (for instance) if you want an opinionated way of organizing your folders, though.

Comment: Tool recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). If you're not interested in running your code through a compiler, check out this answer:

[Constructors in JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects/13736360#13736360)

... explains how I like to set things up so I can have a general "class" structure and keep different parts of the app in different files.

Comment: Agree, I'd recommend typescript too

Answer (score 0):

[Express](http://expressjs.com) is the most used framework for Node.js

Apart, if you are looking for something similar to the relation *ruby - rails* which gives you a predefined project structure (controllers, models...) probably you can take a look to [yeoman](http://yeoman.io)

For an *angular + node* app I'd go with this particular generator: [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack)